# Disabling the built in keyboard and using an external USB keyboard

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard

I spilled coffee on my built in laptop keyboard. As a result, some of the keyboard keys are no longer working. What's worse is that sometimes it gets crazy and some keys are clicking spontaneously. I bought an external USB keyboard but I'm having trouble getting it to work while the built in keyboard is randomly activating keys. I tried uninstalling the keyboard driver using the device manager but when I restart windows re-installs the default driver automatically. I do not know how to disable the built in keyboard. I tried installing the wrong driver but then the keyboard got even more crazy. Can I just try to remove the built in keyboard?

Update: I downloaded DevManView which is an alternative to device manager. It successfully uninstalled the driver (or disabled it I really don't know) but still the keyboard is working. For instance, it keeps clicking on the key 'c' spontaneously. So the question still remains: how can I disable my built-in keyboard? I do not need it. I would be happy to disable it permanently. Please advice.

Thank you

Comment: I know of no way to do this with software. **I think John's answer is your best bet.** I recently replaced my laptop keyboard and it cost about $150 US. It may be possible to simply disconnect it internally (unplug it). I do not know whether your computer would still work though.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the keyboard wiring is unique by laptop manufacturer and sometimes there is other functionality on the keyboard (special functions for the laptop.

I do not recommend removing the keyboard as you / we do not know what it might do when starting, or even if it will start without its own keyboard.

Keyboards are normally inexpensive relative to the cost of the laptop, so I suggest you replace the keyboard.

Since you spilled coffee on the machine, I suggest you take it to a local repair shop and make sure there is no other damage.

If fixing the laptop is not feasible (time limitations) you may need to replace the laptop with a new one.

Comment: Thank you. The machine is working well. I just have to finish work with a deadline today. I can't use any other computer system. I bought a USB keyboard hoping to be able to finish my work, but the built-in keyboard just keeps clicking random keys on its own. I just need to disable it to be able to do my work. It's hard to believe that there are no options to disable that device. Thank you

Comment: You can try removing it, but I think possibly the laptop will not work without out it (even though keys are sticking).  E.g. most laptops know what parts the have.  Also, you likely cannot get into BIOS if you need to with a USB keyboard.

Comment: I think I would have to remove the ribbon cable but I don't have the necessary equipment or the expertise to do so. I wonder if I can make it stop working using software

Comment: It is a hardware issue, so unlikely software can fix it. I replaced the keyboard on my Lenovo X230 because of a defective power button. No way to even turn on the machine without the keyboard.

Comment: But I have a USB keyboard. Can I turn the machine using a US keyboard and no built-in keyboard?

Comment: All you can do is try, but if you do not have the expertise to open the machine and remove cables (you said) I would advise against it and take to a repair shop. i have taken laptops apart myself. I think there is some chance it will not even start without its own keyboard.

Comment: The simplest and easiest method would be to pull that ribbon cable.  However, as you indicate, you don't feel you have the expertise to do that.  However, if you pull that ribbon cable, it still might not solve your problem.  Only replacing the keyboard, which will involve more than just pulling the cable, will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks. I can pull it if it's that simple. If there is a chance my problem won't be solved thought then the only option seems to be to get a new keyboard. But I live now in the US and I bought the laptop some 10 years ago from another country. It's likely I won't find a compatible keyboard for the same model. It looks like I need to buy a new laptop since I don't have the luxury of time. I have a gigantic amount of work to finish in the next few days.

Comment: You can see if Nordic Keyboards (eBay) have your model, but even if so, it takes about a week or so to come. So maybe a new laptop is the way to go in this case. I added that option (obvious last choice) to my answer.